# Message box error when chosing message box icon vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Okay so the program works fine up until this point. The second yesno message box displays exactly how I want it to with no errors. But i want a seperate message box to display to the user when they are in edit mode. (editing things within the program).
The code:

```
    Private Sub Form_formclosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    If inEditMode Then
        Dim dialog As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("You can't exit the program when in edit mode. Please save your changes before exiting the program.")
        If DialogResult = DialogResult.OK Then
            e.Cancel = True
        End If

    Else
        Dim dialog As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to close the program? Any unsaved changes will be lost.", "Exit Application?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)

        If dialog = DialogResult.Yes Then
            Application.ExitThread()
        ElseIf dialog = DialogResult.No Then
            e.Cancel = True
        End If

    End If
End Sub '^warns user before closing the application^
```

The code was working fine until I added a message box icon to the first message box. This is not a functional requirement so it's not neccaserily that important, but it's bugging me that it isn't working.

**edit** BY NOT WORKING I MEAN THE SOLUTION DOES NOT COMPILE

Comment: Please define "not working". Is it not compiling, crashing, having a different comportment from what expected, etc?

Comment: apologies that it wasn't clear enough. It's not compiling. So when i change the code to: Dim dialog As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("You can't exit the program when in edit mode. Please save your changes before exiting the program.", MessageBoxIcon.Error) It does not run and flashes up an error

Comment: I would add a screenshot of the error but I am not allowed due to not having a high enough reputation

Comment: No need. There is no overload which will work that way, that's all. Click insite the parenthese in your code and hit ctrl+shift+spacebar and intellisense will kick in and show you all possible overloads for this function.

Comment: Found a fix thanks to you mate. I needed to add a caption for the message box. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no overload for MessageBox.Show with the 3rd parameter being the MessageBoxIcon.

The closest overload is -> Show(String, String, MessageBoxButtons, MessageBoxIcon)

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show?view=netframework-4.8)

You should be calling the first message box like so:

```
Dim dialog As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Error", "You can't exit the program when in edit mode. Please save your changes before exiting the program.", MessageBoxButtons.Ok, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I managed to work this out with help from laancelot in the comments. I've fixed the error and it's all running the way i wanted it to now.